# Java, editing array from multiple threads

Tags: java, arrays, multithreading, thread-safety

I have many byte arrays of size 4096 (16x16x16), and I want editing them from many threads in one time, there is small chance that any element will be written in one time by more than one thread, and almost impossible that more than 3 will be accessing it (one of elements) in one time (write or read). 
But whole array can be accessed by many threads in one time.

Can this cause any problems? If yes, then how to fix/avoid them? 
I know that reading should be safe, and I hear about some problems with writing 
Code need be fast (real-time based stuff) so I can't synchronize that, and I can't use any ArrayList, because that will cause problems with memory. (There will be like 1000-20000 (or even more) arrays like that)

Comment: 16x16x16 = 4096, not 65536.

Comment: What behavior do you expect from your array when multiple threads are trying to write into the same cell? Here surely can be a problem

Comment: oh, It actually should be 4096, I was thinking about other part of code, sorry.

Comment: @esin88 Yeach, that can be a problem, but, there is **very** small chance that 2 thread will write to this same cell (but array can be edited by more than one), so it can even "choose" random operation. Why there is no AtomicByteArray?

Comment: Why would you need that? Array write operation must be atomic by itself. Of course if you dont do anything else after writing. Although if you expect to see changes made by one thread from another thread, that wouldn't work

Comment: @esin88 That is what I need, other threads must see that change without any problems/delay.

Comment: Nobody can truly answer your question who does not know what the data are supposed to represent, and what operation the threads are performing on it.

Comment: @GotoFinal I would suggest to use AtomicReferenceArray then

Comment: @esin88 it uses Object[] that will take too much memory. Ok, I think that I will just do that in complete other way, with some kind of synchronization.

Comment: You could use an AtomicIntegerArray instead. If you really want to, read the source of it and implement it yourself using s.m.Unsafe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time someone says real time in the same sentence as Java it peaks my interest because real time has a specific meaning that most people don't understand ( oracle / sun have a real time jvm available for purchase )

But I digress , array reads and writes are atomic, therefore thread safe. 2 threads cannot write to the array at the same time because the operation cannot get broken down to anything smaller ( allowing a scheduler to interrupt halfway through ) As long as you are careful ( e.g. Are not reading a value, doing some math and then writing it back to the array and expecting the the value at the given index to remain the same )

So in short there is nothing stopping you from doing this as long as your logic around it is also thread safe.